# Swift - nextDate() search by day of year

Tags: swift, date, datetime, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

Hoping for some help on this one. I'm trying to search (forwards and backwards) to find the next date that matches the **day of the year**

So, for instance I have a day value of 300, I know we are currently on day 237 of this year (as of writing this post, 25/08/18!), and I want to search backwards to find the previous occurrence of the 300th day of a year, and format a date from it.

I'm already extracting the 'day of year' from date using a small Date extension:

```
extension Date {
    var dayOfYear: Int {
        return Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: self)!
    }
}
```

Using the Calendar.nextDate() function I can search to match '.day' , but that's obviously day of month, not year:

```
let potentialSartDate = (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).nextDate(after: nowDate, matching: .day, value: dayOfYearValueToMatch, options: [.matchNextTime, .searchBackwards])!
```

Does anyone have any pointers, or approach, of how to perform a search like this build a date out of the result?

Thanks in advance!

Emile

Comment: Isn't 25/08/18 the 237th day of the year?

Comment: ah, yep, sorry - typo! Corrected in original post ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current year component from today and use the Calendar `date(from: DateComponents)` method to get the 300th day of the year as follow:

```
extension Calendar {
    static let iso8601 = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
}
extension Date {
    var year: Int {
        return Calendar.current.component(.year, from: self)
    }
    var last300ThDayOfYear: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(calendar: .iso8601, year: dayOfYear > 300 ? year  : year - 1, day: 300))!
    }
    var dayOfYear: Int {
        return Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: self)!
    }
}
```

---

```
let date = Date().last300ThDayOfYear  // "Oct 27, 2017 at 12:00 AM"
print(date.dayOfYear)  // 300
```

Comment: Is `last300ThDayOfYear` the last 300th day or day 300 of last year? Will this work in december?

Comment: OP would just need to check if current date day of year > 300

Comment: `return Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(calendar: .iso8601, year: dayOfYear > 300 ? year : year - 1, day: 300))!`

Comment: Leo, perfect. It's kind of what I'd just written down in pseudo-code, so I was thinking along the same lines. Your's is a much cleaner implementation though. Cheers!